# Не работает requests питон

Tags: python, requests, обработка-ошибок

Почему то на одном пк не работает requests выдает ошибку, пробовал переустанавливать его но все равно ошибка.На других пк этот же код работает

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1096, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 642, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 782, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 470, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 514, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1379, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='job.myсайт.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /auth/self-employed/login (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='job.myсайт.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /auth/self-employed/login (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)')))
```

Пользовался вот таким кодом

```
import requests



json = {"phone": f"+12345678910"}
print(json)
#после этой строки происходит ошибка
r = requests.post("https://job.cfqn.ru/auth/self-employed/login", json=json)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: К какому сайту запрос? в логах один сайт, в коде другой.

Comment: @Oopss Там сайт один, прост при скрытии конф данных случайно сделал разный(раскладку менял), на сайт зайти не в рабочей сети невозможно.

Comment: Остается только угадывать, проблемы с ssl, проверьте Дату/время на компьютере.

Comment: @Oopss на других пк работает, дата и время правильные

Comment: Возможно забанили из-за Max retries exceeded with url

Comment: @Oopss вряд ли забанили потому что я сейчас 20 раз на другом пк сделал и вышло просто код 403 и {"systemMessage":"К сожалению, лимит запрашиваемых смс-кодов превышен, попробуйте позже","message":"К сожалению, лимит запрашиваемых смс-кодов превышен, попробуйте позже","errors":{}}
Просто ошибка приходит от сайта а, там именно что при вызове ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилось просто, но довольно странно, на пк на некоторые соединение настроено прокси при принудительном подключении прокси к запросу проблема решилась

Comment: Может вы с зарубежного ip пытались на российский сайт зайти? Многие российские сайты огорожены нынче от доступа из-за рубежа.

Comment: @CrazyElf да нет ПК в РФ да и инет тоже в РФ, сайт вроде тоже РФ. прокси тобе РФ